# Jquery very slow in IE

Tags: jquery

could anyoone help me and tell why my superfish and slide menu 
are very slow in IE 6/7 and fast as hell in FF?

I think is because of jquery used in template. 
Template was prucased from template monster (32021) and I just 
changed pictures and links.

Site address is http://www.blb-invest.com

Thanks in advance
Darko

Comment: IE has a terrible JS engine compared to Firefox, which is saying something as Firefox's JS engine is terrible compared to Chrome.  It's a major issue.

Answer (score 4):

It's mainly because FF has native support for many functions that IE just doesn't (for instance getElementByClassName is native to FF but not in IE). For IE jQuery has to walk the dom in ways that aren't always the most efficient. Also there is the js engine for IE6/7 aren't as fast/optimized as the javascript engine for Firefox. IE8 and IE9 are much better in terms of speed but they still lack some of the base functions that FF and Chrome offer. One of the things to look for in the jQuery code for those two plugins are searches by classname and the use of the each function. The jQuery each function is extremely slow and should be replaced. Also classname searches will be slow (should be based at an ID root node with a find) because non rooted class name searches have to start from the root of the document.

Comment: You might also check out this link on what someone did to fix slow animation in IE7: http://yourcodegarage.com/blog/2009/09/fixing-slow-jquery-animations-in-internet-explorer/. It basically has to do with what you are doing with CSS.

Comment: +1 I agree with this answer.  because you are using a template, there could be another things they are doing that are potentially not optimized or uses "hacks" for backwards compatability.  To optimize the site I would replace animations with simple hide/show, remove any PNG conversion, and get rid of opacity.

Comment: For the fade in's you could check out what they did in this blog: http://www.kevinleary.net/jquery-fadein-fadeout-problems-in-internet-explorer/

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't seem like a matter of speed to me. It looks like IE is having trouble with the transparency on the `.fadeIn()`. Try using `.show()` or something similar without an animation and see how it runs.